# Error when pulling data from SAP data source using table connector

Tags: json, google-cloud-data-fusion, sap-basis, cdap

EDIT: I am using Cloud Fusion (CDAP) on GCP.

When validating a data pipeline that pulls data from SAP using the table connector, I get this error:

> Invalid schema: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 2 path $

I reckon it might be data coming from SAP being invalid, but how and where do I setup the `setLenient` property?

It used to work fine until recently and changes were made so I suspect data might be making our pipeline break but I have no idea how to set the property.

I don't know what to try and I suspect the JSON describing the schema is invalid but I have no idea how to solve the issue or if there is a solution available on Cloud Fusion or if this is something to fix on SAP.

Comment: Sorry, I am using Cloud Fusion (CDAP) on GCP.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working properly previously then can you confirm whether you are using the newly added feature '*Snapshot*' as '*true*'?
In case it's true then you must have to import the latest Transport available on hub as well.
There is no direct way of setting this 'setLenient' property, this error pop-up whenever there's malformed JSON coming to plugin.
If you make '*Snapshot*' as '*false*' then it will continue to work as before and no JSON data will be involved.